# WcfTestClient: The contract 'IMetadataExchange' error

Tags: wcf, web-services, wcftestclient

I created WCF service application there are no errors until I run `WcfTestClient`. It requires `IMetadataExchange` to be configured.

How to configure `IMetadataExchange` or avoid of its usage?

**Error:**

> --------------------------- Microsoft WCF Test Client
>   --------------------------- The contract 'IMetadataExchange' in client configuration does not match the name in service contract, or there is
>   no valid method in this contract. To recover, please manually correct
>   client configuration.
>
> Or restore to default configuration.
>
> Or check "Always regenerate config when launching services" in the
>   Tools -> Options menu, then refresh the service.

**App.config**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfCrmService.PermitTypesService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WcfCrmService.IPermitTypesService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="WcfCrmService.IPermitTypesService" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfCrmService/Mex/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

**PermitTypes**

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace WcfCrmService
{
    namespace TestService
    {
        [DataContract]
        public class PermitTypes
        {
            [DataMember]
            public Guid PermitTypesId;

            [DataMember]
            public String PermitName;

            [DataMember]
            public String PermitForm;

            [DataMember]
            public String PermitView;
        }
    }
}
```

**IPermitTypesService**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ServiceModel;
using WcfCrmService.TestService;

namespace WcfCrmService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IPermitTypesService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void SubmitPermitTypes(PermitTypes permit);

        [OperationContract]
        List<PermitTypes> GetPermitTypes();

        [OperationContract]
        void DeletePermitTypes(string id);
    }
}
```

**PermitTypesService**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.SWSE;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client;
using WcfCrmService.TestService;
namespace WcfCrmService
{
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
    public class PermitTypesService : IPermitTypesService
    {
        public void SubmitPermitTypes(PermitTypes permit)
        {
            // Create records
        }
        public List<PermitTypes> GetPermitTypes()
        {
            // return Results
        }
        public void DeletePermitTypes(string id)
        {
            // Remove items
        }
    }
}
```

### Service XML

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1" u:Id="_2">http://tempuri.org/IPermitTypesService/GetPermitTypesResponse</a:Action>
    <a:RelatesTo u:Id="_3">urn:uuid:6f8c2229-da22-4ea1-b0df-e760bf51af6d</a:RelatesTo>
    <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <u:Timestamp u:Id="uuid-090f17e6-f7a7-4e9c-8881-d19571706129-17">
        <u:Created>2011-07-15T10:35:14.132Z</u:Created>
        <u:Expires>2011-07-15T10:40:14.132Z</u:Expires>
      </u:Timestamp>
      <c:DerivedKeyToken u:Id="uuid-090f17e6-f7a7-4e9c-8881-d19571706129-7" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc">
        <o:SecurityTokenReference>
          <o:Reference URI="urn:uuid:1716f576-883e-475c-9b56-4accac413b66" ValueType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc/sct" />
        </o:SecurityTokenReference>
        <c:Offset>0</c:Offset>
        <c:Length>24</c:Length>
        <c:Nonce>GAplsFZPK8LsfnWQDwrTkQ==</c:Nonce>
      </c:DerivedKeyToken>
      <c:DerivedKeyToken u:Id="uuid-090f17e6-f7a7-4e9c-8881-d19571706129-8" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc">
        <o:SecurityTokenReference>
          <o:Reference URI="urn:uuid:1716f576-883e-475c-9b56-4accac413b66" ValueType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc/sct" />
        </o:SecurityTokenReference>
        <c:Nonce>xwL0WRp3kTTqjzEwwFnA3A==</c:Nonce>
      </c:DerivedKeyToken>
      <e:ReferenceList xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
        <e:DataReference URI="#_1" />
        <e:DataReference URI="#_4" />
      </e:ReferenceList>
      <e:EncryptedData Id="_4" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element" xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
        <e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc" />
        <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
          <o:SecurityTokenReference>
            <o:Reference ValueType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc/dk" URI="#uuid-090f17e6-f7a7-4e9c-8881-d19571706129-8" />
          </o:SecurityTokenReference>
        </KeyInfo>
        <e:CipherData>
          <e:CipherValue>CIPHERDATAK</e:CipherValue>
        </e:CipherData>
      </e:EncryptedData>
    </o:Security>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body u:Id="_0">
    <GetPermitTypesResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <GetPermitTypesResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfCrmService.TestService" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <a:PermitTypes>
          <a:PermitForm>TESTPERMIT_FORM</a:PermitForm>
          <a:PermitName>TESTPERMIT_NAME</a:PermitName>
          <a:PermitTypesId>d81a9ccd-bbae-e011-9b4f-bcaec545c264</a:PermitTypesId>
          <a:PermitView>TESTPERMIT_VIEW</a:PermitView>
        </a:PermitTypes>
        <a:PermitTypes>
          <a:PermitForm>BcisCertificate</a:PermitForm>
          <a:PermitName>Сертификат соответствия БЦИС</a:PermitName>
          <a:PermitTypesId>167ac5ea-51a9-e011-9c96-bcaec545c264</a:PermitTypesId>
          <a:PermitView>BcisCertificateView</a:PermitView>
        </a:PermitTypes>
        <a:PermitTypes>
          <a:PermitForm>DLOReferenceForm</a:PermitForm>
          <a:PermitName>Справка ДЛО</a:PermitName>
          <a:PermitTypesId>16579d03-52a9-e011-9c96-bcaec545c264</a:PermitTypesId>
          <a:PermitView>DLOReferenceView</a:PermitView>
        </a:PermitTypes>
      </GetPermitTypesResult>
    </GetPermitTypesResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Sultan

Comment: Have you tried regenerating the client? Or what are the steps that you followed, which resulted in the error message?

Comment: I implemented step-by-step DataContract, Service Contract interface and derived service interface as show above

Comment: I also tried rebuild the solution again but with no result

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! If you post error messages, **please** use the blockquotes ( ` " ` ) to properly format the error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This here in your configuration is definitely wrong:

```
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="WcfCrmService.IPermitTypesService" />
```

A MEX endpoint for metadata exchange **must** have the WCF built-in contract `IMetadataExchange` and **not** your own service contract.

Try using this:

```
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
```

Does this work now?? The WCF Test Client would use the MEX endpoint to learn about your service - if you had a wrong service contract in there, the Test Client certainly wouldn't work....

**Update:** your choice of a base address also is a bit strange:

```
<baseAddresses>
   <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfCrmService/Mex/" />
</baseAddresses>
```

This mean: your actual service is reachable at:

```
http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfCrmService/Mex/
```

while your MEX endpoint is reached at:

```
http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfCrmService/Mex/mex/
```

I would recommend using a better/more meaningful base address for the service and just add `mex` to the end of the MEX endpoint:

```
<baseAddresses>
   <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/Services/WcfCrmService/" />
</baseAddresses>
```

Comment: @Sultan: what **URL** do you connect to when using the WCF Test Client??

Comment: Currently I'm using ASP.NET development server

Comment: @Sultan: two things to check: does WCF Test Client work with this URL: `http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfCrmService/mex/mex` , and second: do you get anything when connecting a browser to `ttp://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfCrmService/mex?wsdl` ??

Comment: @marc_s let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1503/discussion-between-sultan-and-marc-s)

Comment: I ran into the error when I run default WCF service library project

Comment: If you fixed your web config and endpoints and still getting that message, you probably use some adapter (BizTalk or CRM) installed on your machine. Go through [this answer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wcftoolsteamblog/archive/2008/08/28/tips-for-wcf-tools-in-vs2008-sp1.aspx) to fix the issue. Refer to the last section about commenting the client mex endpoints in machine.config